# FxCop CA1305: CurrentCulture vs. CurrentUICulture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, string-formatting, currentculture, currentuiculture

So, I have a few resource files for localization. They're strings that can be formatted.

For example:

```
MyResource.resx
 Title: "MyApp - Ver: {0}"
```

I then return it by doing like so:

```
public String Title
{
    get { return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, MyResources.Title, 1); }
}
```

I understand the difference between CurrentUICulture and CurrentCulture, but FxCop is telling me to use CurrentCulture instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To some extent FxCop is right: you should not use `CurrentUICulture` in this case. As others already said, `CurrentCulture` is meant for Locale-aware formatting, whereas `CurrentUICulture` is meant for reading translatable strings from resources.
What you did here, was formatting number, therefore FxCop complains that you used incorrect `CultureInfo`. Unfortunately, what FxCop did not tell you is, you should in fact use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Why? Because version number is something that does not depend on Locale. You will always see something like 1.9 and not something like 1,9. Thus `InvariantCulture` is the way to go.
Microsoft even provided specific class to store version information - oddly enough its name is `Version` (AFAIR it is in `System` namespace). This will always present you version numbers like I mentioned before, when you do `ToString()`. Its constructor also expects Locale-invariant version string when you instantiate it.

Answer (score 5):

`String.Format` is often going to be used for numeric or date formatting, which is based on `CurrentCulture` rather than `CurrentUICulture`.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing is that `CurrentUICulture` can be a neutral culture while `CurrentCulture` is always a specific culture.

The `XXXFormatInfo` types do not work with neutral cultures and will raise a `NotSupportedException` exception.